# Minus (-) 15 mins from the Current Date Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

What would be the syntax to minus 15 mins from current datetime

I am using it in `WHERE` clause

For Example

```
Where DateTime = GetDate() -15 min
```

It should get the current DateTime & minus 15 mins from it .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEADD` function in SQL Server.

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

or

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())
```

**CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** is an ANSI SQL function whereas **GETDATE** is the T-SQL version of that same function.

More information about `DATEADD` you can find on this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Note that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Use LOCALTIMESTAMP to get without time zone.

Comment: I don't think so, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GETDATE() return the same result in the SQL Server. Your definition is related to Oracle.

Comment: "My" definition is cut-and-paste from ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), i.e. the ISO/ANSI SQL specification. (I didn't know SQL Server had CURRENT_TIME.)

Comment: You can check Microsoft documentation, just read first paragraph:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Function.

**Query**

```
Select dateadd(minute, -15, getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateadd()`:

```
select dateadd(minute, -15, getdate())
```

Incidentally, the SQL standard syntax (which is not supported in SQL Server) is:

```
select current_timestamp - interval '15 minute'
```

Comment: ANSI SQL has `select current_timestamp - interval '15' minute`